# How to determine which objects do not support Modify All and View All permissions?

Tags: permissions, standard-objects

All custom objects and most standard objects support `Modify All` and `View All` permissions, however, some like object like `Idea` do not support them.

Is there a way in Apex to determine which objects do not support `Modify All` and `View All` permissions?

Answer (score 1):

As per [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=users_profiles_view_all_mod_all.htm&type=5), this is indeed mentioned:

> View All and Modify All are not available for ideas, price books, article types, and products.

A possible workaround can be to query on `ObjectPermissions` and checking for System administrator profile object permission based on profile permissions `PermissionsViewAllData` and `PermissionsModifyAllData`.

SOQL on `ObjectPermissions` for system admin profile seems to always return 2 records by object with `PermissionsViewAllRecords` and `PermissionsModifyAllRecords` true for both records.

Except if you query for one of those objects not valid for `View All` and `Modify All`, then you will notice that one of the record shows false for both `PermissionsViewAllRecords` and `PermissionsModifyAllRecords` for system admin.

**1) Query for Idea object**

```
SELECT Id, SObjectType ,Parent.Profile.Name, PermissionsModifyAllRecords, PermissionsViewAllRecords 
FROM ObjectPermissions
WHERE Parent.IsOwnedByProfile =true and Parent.IsCustom = false
AND SObjectType = 'Idea'
AND Parent.Profile.PermissionsViewAllData =true 
AND Parent.Profile.PermissionsModifyAllData = true
```

**Result:**

[image]

**2) Query for Account object**

```
SELECT Id, SObjectType ,Parent.Profile.Name, PermissionsModifyAllRecords, PermissionsViewAllRecords 
FROM ObjectPermissions
WHERE Parent.IsOwnedByProfile =true and Parent.IsCustom = false and SObjectType = 'Account'
AND Parent.Profile.PermissionsViewAllData =true 
AND Parent.Profile.PermissionsModifyAllData = true
```

**Result:**

[image]

**Conclusion**

If you run this SOQL, you can have a list of all objects for which object permissions `View All` and `Modify all` are not valid.

```
SELECT Id, SObjectType ,Parent.Profile.Name, PermissionsModifyAllRecords, PermissionsViewAllRecords 
FROM ObjectPermissions
WHERE Parent.IsOwnedByProfile =true and Parent.IsCustom = false
and Parent.Profile.PermissionsViewAllData =true 
and Parent.Profile.PermissionsModifyAllData = true
and PermissionsModifyAllRecords = false
and PermissionsViewAllRecords = false
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: It is not viable to query permission by name of profile since this name may be different in different user locales, so if organization with French or German language will have different profile name and these queries will fail

Comment: @Patlatus Correct. I've revised my answer to remove reference to system admin profile name and deriving this by checking profile permissions `PermissionsViewAllData` and `PermissionsModifyAllData` instead. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

[DescribeSObjectResult](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject_describe.htm) doesn't provide any way to verify this.

So, a manual list can be created.

For the current release, the following
`Idea`, `Pricebook2`, `Product2`, `PushTopic` do not support `Modify All` and `View All` permissions